# Repl.it and FFmpeg

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, replit

Hi I am building a discord bot and would like to use ffmpeg in it but am working on [repl.it](https://repl.it). How can I use ffmpeg on repl.it if I can?

This is for translating a .webm file into an .mp4 file, running on python 3.7.4. I have had a look on the repl.it forums and on Stack Overflow but cannot find any information.

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to use the packages menu to install ffmpeg but it says that it can't find it in /bin/sh when I try to run a command to convert a .webm to a .mp4 using os.popen()

Comment: You can use Replit's nix feature by running `ffmpeg` in the shell and select yes on the prompt to install.

Answer (score 5):

You can download **i686 of ffmpeg** compressed file from this [link](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

After downloading it, extract it, then upload the **ffmpeg** file inside to your repl.it project.

You can use the replit built in shell

```
chmod +777 ./ffmpeg
```

After that, type in

```
ffmpeg [command]
```

into the shell

[Example](https://repl.it/@a09222656836/ffmpegtest)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use ffmpeg on `Repl.it`. However, you can run a discord bot on `Repl.it`, at least one that doesn't use audio. Based on the programming language you are using, I strongly suggest a service such as [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com).

Answer (score -2):

TRY USING `

> install ffmpeg-static

`

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, you don't have to scream